# Finding three numbers whose sum is divisible by a given number

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

How can I search through an array and find every combination of three values whose sum is divisible by a given number(x) in java.

In other words, every combination where (n1+n2+n3) % x == 0.

I know this would be a simple solution using a triple for loop but I need something with a time complexity of O(N^2).

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Hash every (element % x) in the list.

2 - Sum every pair of elements in the list (lets call the sum y) and do modded_y = y % x.

3 - Check if x - modded_y is in the hash table. If it is and it's not one of the other 2 numbers then you found a possible combination. Keep iterating and hashing the combinations you found so that they don't repeat.

This is called a meet in the middle strategy.

It's complexity is O(n + (n^2 * 1)) = O(n^2)

Comment: What are the first and second lists?

Comment: Looks like this finds one combination, is that right? The challenge is to find all combinations.

Comment: Yes you are right... I got excited to answer and didnt read it carefuly :/ The answer can be easily extended though. Will update it again and hopefully not screw up again.

Answer (score 0):

I will call the given array A1.

1) create two structs

```html
struct pair{
int first;
int second;
bool valid; 
}
```

```html
struct third{
int value;
int index; 
}
```

2) using a nested loop, initialize an array B1 of all possible Pairs.

3) Loop through B1. if (A1[B1[i].first] + A1[B1[i].second])%x==0 then set B1[i].valid to true

4) create an array A3 of Thirds that stores the index and value of every element from A1 that is divisible by x.

5) using a nested loop, go through each element of A3 and each element of B1. If B1.valid = true 
print A1[B1[i].first] and A1[B1[i].second] with an element from A1[A3.index].

that should give you all combinations without using any triple loops.

Comment: I think, it would be better if you posted the complete code for your solution instead of describing it in words.

Comment: I don't understand this solution. A triple will only be valid if the sum of element 1 and 2 is divisible and the third element is also disivible? What about if x is 5 and the list is [1, 2, 3]?

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer, only the pair 2,3 would make it to A2 because (2+3)%5 = 0 but 1%5 != 0 so that would not make it to A3. My program would therefore reject the triple [1,2,3] .....

Comment: @EduardMalakhov this question sounds a little bit like homework... according to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ---  "It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment.... " I can probably provide the program if the original asker can validify that this is not homework.